# document.getElementById("FileUpload1"); is giving null/undefined value in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the file name in Chrome browser but in IE i am getting null value.
I want to display choose file name in asp.net html and java script only.
The attached code is below

```
var files = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
```

is giving me null / undefined value and

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").files[0].name
```

is giving the error asUnable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

```js
function showFileName() { 
    document.getElementById("FileUploadedLabel").style.color = "black";
    var files = document.getElementById("FileUpload1"); 
    if(files != null && files != undefined && files != 'undefined') { 
        var fileName = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").files[0].name; 
        document.getElementById("FileUploadedLabel").innerHTML = "File name:-" + fileName;
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="FileUpload1">
        <img src="button_choose-file.png" class="image" style="height:30px; width:100px" />
    </label>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" Style=" display:none;" onmouseover="mouseOverUpload()" onmouseout="mouseOutUpload()" Onchange="showFileName()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable - all relevant information should be in the question itself

Comment: Add it to the question. Not as comments

Comment: I have removed the code from comments.If you have any solution please give me

Comment: Are you sure it's that line of code causing the error? It could be `document.getElementById("FileUploadedLabel").style.color` because I cannot see an element with that ID in your question

Comment: Got the solution posted below

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showFileName(fileInput) {
    var files = ((typeof fileInput === 'string' && (fileInput = fileInput.match(/[^\\\/]+$/)) && fileInput[0]) || '')
    document.getElementById("FileUploadedLabel").innerHTML = "File name:" + files;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" Onchange="showFileName(this.value)"/>
    </html>
    </body>
```